# how to solve kawahara equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, maple

the numerical solution to a problem involving a nonlinear partial differential equation of the form below

$u_t + uu_x + u_{3x} − u_{5x} = 0$

$u(x, 0) = f (x) , x ∈ R$

which is called Kawahara equation?

I have this adomian solution maple code to solve it but it brings me lots of error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scKdO.png]

have you any idea?

Comment: Hope [that](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-password-2008/ams-password41-44-2008/matinfarAMS41-44-2008.pdf) helps.

Comment: What is the meaning of $u_{3x}$ and $u_{5x}$ ?

Comment: @doraemonpaul : I mean $ u_{3x} = {{\partial^3 u\over\partial x^3}} $ 3 times diffrential over u on x

Comment: @venna : thanks cenrtaily it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

greath thanks to @venna, @doraemonpaul & @sajadi who helped me solve this, the final answer which I expected is as bellow:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this way I finally could solve it, I did not want to leave this opened in here!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the great things in http://www.isrn.com/journals/mp/2012/185469.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution of Kawahara equation from the research paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042709004038#